# Where is pip installed to when using get-pip.py?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I just installed pip on OS X using the [get-pip.py](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) script provided by the developers. The script said it ran successfully, but I cannot execute `pip` from the command line. I guess `pip` is not in my path, but I don't know where it installed to so I can't add it to the path. Any help would be most excellent. Thanks!

When I attempt to run the install script again, here is the output:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 60):

If you can't find the path to `pip` you can simply use `python -m pip` instead:

```
python -m pip install awesome_package
```

Comment: `python -m pip install awesome_package --user` to install as user (if you get permission denied error)

Answer (score 18):

Do you know your **python path**? If yes, then look under the **Scripts** directory.

For me (Windows user), `pip` it is located in

> C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe

Correspondingly for Linux, it should be inside

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip

Also, if you have [`Homebrew`](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) installed, pip installs with python:

> brew install python

And, the fact that you have python & pip installed & cannot get pip but can get python from the command line (path), pip must have been misconfigured.

If you still can't find it, you can use `locate pip` for Linux, or a corresponding search method for other OSs. Also, in your case, it already seems to be in

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages

as per the output message.

Comment: I have Python 3.3 installed, but I only see python versions 2.7 and prior in `/usr/lib/python*`. I don't have homebrew installed, so I can't install python that way.

Answer (score 15):

On linux you can use:

```
which pip
```

To find the location of pip.

Comment: This doesn't help if the executable is not in your PATH which is the problem Max is having

Comment: That is an excellent point.  You can also do `sudo updatedb; locate pip` if you have the `mlocate` package installed.

Comment: `whereis pip` also can be used.

Answer (score 5):

### pip binary is named pip3 for python 3

If you are getting a message `Requirement already up-to-date` that means pip is already installed on your system and you either don't have the directory which contains the pip program in your path or you are not calling pip correctly.

If you are using bash, type "pi" and hit tab twice. You will get commands starting with pi and hopefully you will see pip3. Here's why:

If you installed `pip` using `get-pip.py` and you installed it using a python 3 then the `pip` binary is stored as `pip3`. Try running the command `pip3` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the installation path. It is located here:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip`

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was in the directory below and I created an alias to just be able to run it with `pip`.

`alias pip='python /lnx510/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip'`

Answer (score 1):

here you can find where the pip packages are., 
In linux

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

on mac

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```