# sudo and pip not on the same path

Tags: python, path, sudo

`pip` and `sudo` are not on the same path on my machine, so when (basically all the time) I need to run both commands, like so:

```
sudo pip install xxx
```

I get:

`sudo: pip: command not found`

`pip` downloads packages, but since access is being denied at the end of installation, it ends up failing.

by doing `pip -V`, (`which pip` returns nothing) I get to know where pip is:

```
pip 1.5.4 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

and by doing `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'`,

I get:

```
/usr/bin:~/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/Zed.app/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

I have tried to symlink pip into sudo's directories, like so:

`$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip`, to no avail.

How do I put `sudo` on the same `path`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is pip installed to when using get-pip.py?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278138/where-is-pip-installed-to-when-using-get-pip-py)

Comment: not a duplicate. `pip` is on my `path`. `sudo pip` isn't.

Comment: duplicate of: [Command not found when using sudo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83194, you should be able to run this command like this:

```
sudo env 'PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin' pip ...
```

Comment: as in `sudo 'PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin' pip install xxx`? this does not work: still: `sudo: pip: command not found`

Comment: Ok.  I updated the post, and this time I tested it and am sure it works.

Comment: I get `env: pip: No such file or directory`. maybe `pip` is not in `usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Try the command `which pip`.  That should tell you where the pip executable is located.

Comment: I have. please refer to question: which pip returns nothing. in which case the question is: where does pip executable lives?

Comment: If you don't have the `which` command, you can try `locate pip` or `find / -name "pip"` (this second one may take a little time).

Comment: doing that. will let you know

Comment: Alternately, you can run pip like this: `sudo python -c 'import pip; pip.main()' ...`.

Comment: Can I have the bounty?

Comment: sorry, I thought it was granted to you after I'd accepted your answer. there you go.

Answer (score 9):

After installing pip, I did

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip
```

and now root can use pip without any PATH modifications. I had trouble making PATH modifications to the root account.

Answer (score 0):

You tried just doing sudo su and seeing if it works?

Comment: it gives me: `sh-3.2# `

Comment: Yes, now you are root. Try running "pip install package" now. The sudo command is just a command to make you temporarily root. sudo su logs you in as root.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your root account has a different set of paths to your lower user account. Do you have a custom .bashrc?

Comment: I have, but not doing much. how could it help me?

Comment: Well, if you have a PATH set in that file, it could be why only that account finds it. I was going to comment on someone else's answer but don't have enough reputation yet so I'll comment here. run "which pip" in the terminal. This should tell you where it is located. Then do "sudo <whatever it returned>". If you want a one liner to do all that, this should do it - "sudo `which pip`" <-- note the backticks, they must be in place for this to work. Obviously remove the quotation marks though. edit - The post formatting here strips the backticks out. They are around the whereis pip command

Answer (score 0):

Wherever pip lives, it's not in your path when you sudo. So try this:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip
```

If that doesn't work, then say `which pip` to find out where pip lives, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: `sudo: /usr/local/bin/pip: command not found`, and `which pip` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like pip is not installed at system level.
You can install `pip` at system level by running `sudo apt-get install python-pip` from terminal.After this you can upgrade `pip` by running `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` .

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" pip install xxx`, you should be able to run the right `pip` executable.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
sudo -H <your_commands>
```

?

This should preserve your user environment.