# Python 3, Pip3, and Sudo. Sudo has no access to pip installed packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

I'm trying to figure out why my sudo doesn't have access to pip installed packages. Here is the details of my setup below.

Ubuntu 20.04, Fresh install. Comes with Python3.8.
Install some other package, which installs its own Python (Intel MKL Oneapi), which is Python3.9.  This install somehow makes that the default Python.  I get around this by editting ~/.bashrc to explicitly target /usr/bin/python3 (which is 3.8) for python/python3 and pip/pip3 each.

I do

`pip install packaging`

I launch python with

`python3` which correctly targets the alias'd `/usr/bin/python3` and I am able to do `import packaging` without issue.

In a script, I import packaging. If I run

`python3 setup.py install`

I get an error with a permission denied :

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/test-    easy-install-8015.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/
```

`

So I then try

`sudo python3 setup.py install`

However I am now back to `No module named packaging`

SO I am curious, why does `sudo` not have access to this package?

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41734077/14901922

Comment: Not particularly.  This explains how to avoid the issue, but not really why my sudo would have access to Python, but would not have access to the packages installed in that version of Python.