# how to install Pip3 on windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I installed Python 3.10 today but when I try to run pip or pip3, the command prompt gives me an error. I tried following the instructions that the top answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501636/how-to-install-pip3-on-windows) said. My complete path to the python interpreter is this:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe
```

In the `WindowsApps` directory, I'm supposed to have a `Scripts` folder. Strangely enough, I don't. Can someone please help me?

Comment: did you select add to path during installation?

Comment: I don't remember. is there a way I could change that option now? Or would i have to reinstall the interpreter?

Comment: pip3 should be installed when you install python. if you didn't select the add to path, then you can find where the pip3 located and add it to path manually or you can reinstall.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't see pip or pip3 anywhere on the system when running 'where pip' or 'where pip3'. I guess my best option is to reinstall?

Comment: running this command won't return anything if you haven't configured pip, you have to manually find it in the installation directory of python and configure it, check this ticket out it could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278138/where-is-pip-installed-to-when-using-get-pip-py

Comment: check if there is Scripts folder in this path `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\`

Comment: @RamaSalahat `py -m pip` did the trick. now the question is how do I execute pip without typing `py -m`?

Comment: just type something like `pip list` or `pip install XXX` in the console to make sure it's working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if pip3 is already installed

`pip3 -v`

if it is installed the output should be like that

```
C:\Python38\python.exe -m pip <command> [options]

Commands:

  install      Install packages.

  download                    Download packages.

  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.

  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.

  list                        List installed packages.

  show                        Show information about installed packages.

  ...

  ...
```

Pip3 Upgrade

```
python -m pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Pip3 Downgrade

```
python -m pip3 install pip==19.0
```

Comment: You led me to the right path. Thank you. After upgrading pip, it said that it wasn't in the path. Also thanks @mirodil for mentioning that too

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following post

[How can I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-can-i-install-pip-on-windows)

`py -3 -m ensurepip`

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml'

Answer (score 0):

You can try `python -m pip` to use pip if it is installed.

If pip is not installed, you can always use `python -m ensurepip --upgrade` to install pip for your python installation.